# Two contexts, same tables, needs to change in some of them - other stay the same

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two projects that depend on two different db contexts. The projects use EF code first. Te thing is the contexts have multiple(5 to be exact) common tables. So the use the same class to create the entity. The problem is that now this class needs to change(columns/propertys to be added) for one of the contexts, but to stay the same for the other.

So for example I have:

```
public interface IPeopleFirstGroupDbContxt 
{
  IDbSet<Person> Person {get; set;}
  IDbSet<Grade> Grades {get; set;}
  IDbSet<Book> Books {get; set;}
} 

public interface IPeopleSecondGroupDbContxt 
{
  IDbSet<Person> Person {get; set;}
  IDbSet<Grade> Grades {get; set;}
  IDbSet<Book> Books {get; set;}
  IDbSet<Hobbie> Hobbies {get; set;}
  IDbSet<School> Schools {get; set;}
} 

public class Person(
{
  public Person()
  {
    this.Grades = new HashSet<Grade>();
    this.Books= new HashSet<Book>();
  }

  [Key]
  public int PersonId {get; set;}
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public ICollection Grades {get; set;}
  public ICollection Books{get; set;}
}
```

For the `IPeopleSecondGroupDbContxt` db context in table `Person` new one to many relationship to Hobbies shoud be added without changing the `IPeopleFirstGroupDbContxt` and Person table in `IPeopleFirstGroupDbContxt`.
 - In this case I can't make Person class abstract and inherit it because this one to many relationship doesn't work. It just creates new column in Hobiie class, but doesn't exactly create the relationship. 
 - Second chance is just to inherit from Person -> NewPerson, without making it abstract, but this will create relationship between these two tables by PersonId

Any ides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, relational databases don't handle inheritance very well, and thus entity framework has to work around it if you want to use inheritance.

The problem is that your DbSet classes hold the properties that represent the columns in the tables (the real information), but also the properties that represent the relationships between the tables: the ICollection and the foreign key.

Apparently a `Grade` has a one-to-many relation to a `Person`: every `Person` has zero or more `Grades`, every `Grade` belongs to exactly one `Person`.

In your other database you don't have `Persons`, you have `ExtendedPersons`. `ExtendedPersons` are very similar to `Persons`, for instance, every `ExtendedPerson` has zero or more Grades. However, `ExtendededPersons` have something more. `ExtendedPersons` also have `Hobbies` and `Books`. Because of the similarity with `Persons` you decided to use inheritance.

In your other database a `Grade` is different than a `Grade` in your first database. A Grade is not a `Grade` of a `Person`, it is a grade of an `ExtendedPerson`.

If you don't want to create a separate `ExtendedGrade` class, you need fluent API to inform entity framework about this different relation. The best method, which won't interfere with your basic classes is the use of fluent API in `OnModelCreating`

The Persons:

```
class Person
{
     public int Id {get; set;}

     // every Person has zero or more PersonGrades (one-to-many
     public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades {get; set;}

     ... // other properties
}

class ExtendedPerson : Person
{
     // inherits primary key and Grades from Person

     // every ExtendedPerson has zero or more Hobbies (one-to-many)
     public virtual ICollection<Hobby> Hobbies {get; set;}

     ...
}
```

Grades and Hobbies:

```
class Grade
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Grade belongs to exactly one (subclass of) Person using foreign key
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public virtual Person Person {get; set;}
}

class Hobby
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Hobby belongs to exactly one ExtendedPerson using foreign key
    public int ExtendedPersonId {get; set;}
    public virtual ExtendedPerson ExtendedPerson {get; set;}
}
```

Your first DbContext:

```
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Person> Persons {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Grade> Grades {get; set;}   

     public override void OnModelCreating(...)
     {
         // a person has zero or more Grades,
         // every Grade belongs to exactly one Person
         // using foreign key PersonId
         modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
             .HasMany(person => person.Grades)
             .WithRequired(grade => grade.Person)
             .HasForeignKey(grade => grad.PersonId);
     }
}
```

Your other DbContext:

```
public MyOtherDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<ExtendePerson> ExtendedPersons {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Grade> Grades {get; set;}   
     public DbSet<Hobby> Hobbies {get; set;}

     public override void OnModelCreating(...)
     {
         // every extended person has zero or more Grades
         // every Grade belongs to exactly one Person
         // using foreign key PersonId
         modelBuilder.Entity<ExtendedPerson>()
             .HasMany(extendedPerson => extendedPerson.Grades)
             .WithRequired(grade => grade.Person)
             .HasForeignKey(grade => grade.PersonId);

         // every extended person has zero or more hobbies
         // every hobby belongs to exactly one ExtendedPerson
         // using foreign  key ExtendedPersonId
         modelBuilder.Entity<ExtendedPerson>()
             .HasMany(extendedPerson => extendedPerson.Hobbies)
             .WithRequired(hobby => hobby.ExtendedPerson)
             .HasForeignKey(hobby => hobby.ExtendedPersonId);

         // proper table name for hobbies:
         modelBuilder.Entity<Hobby>().ToTable("Hobbies");
     }
}
```